# React styleguidedist, npx styleguidist build doesn't find font files import in css

Tags: reactjs, font-face, react-styleguidist

I've an issue when i build styleguide "npx styleguidist build", i haven't this when i run "npx styleguidist server". In css file generated by styleguidist build, the link to fonts doesn't match with what is in build folder :

```
src:url(static/media/GothamRounded-Light.a6caeaca.woff2)
```

It works if i replace this url in css builded file by :

```
src:url(../media/GothamRounded-Light.a6caeaca.woff2)
```

See build folder's tree : [picture of styleguidedist build's folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKDKp.png)

styleguide.config.js :

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    require: [
        path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/scss/app.scss'),
    ],
    updateExample(props, exampleFilePath) {
        const { settings, lang } = props
        if (settings && typeof settings.file === 'string') {
            const filepath = path.resolve(
                path.dirname(exampleFilePath),
                settings.file
            )
            const { file, ...restSettings } = settings
            return {
                content: fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8'),
                settings: restSettings,
                lang
            }
        }
        return props
    },
    sections: [
        {
            name: 'UI Components',
            components: 'src/components/**/*.jsx',
            exampleMode: 'collapse', // 'hide' | 'collapse' | 'expand'
            usageMode: 'collapse', // 'hide' | 'collapse' | 'expand'
            collapseCode: true,
         }
    ],
}
```